# Sum of the number of relatively prime integers up to $x$, $x-1$, $\ldots$, $1$

Tags: totient-function, coprime

If there is a number $x$, and we want to find the sum of the number of relatively prime integers up to $x$, $x-1$, $\dots$ until $1$, is there a formula for this or any way to solve it? Like if the number is $6$, you add up $0$ (for numbers relatively prime to $1$), $1$ (for numbers relatively prime to $2$), $2$ (for $3$), $2$ (for $4$), $4$ (for $5$), and $2$ (for $6$) for a total of $11$ numbers. I tried using Euler's Totient Function, but with a high number, that would require far too many computations. Is there any way to compute this for a high number, let's say $2019$, without taking a lot of time?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientSummatoryFunction.html

Comment: So basically you want to compute $\sum_{i\leq n} \varphi(i)$?

Comment: Yes but how do you compute it?

Comment: "let's say 2019" That's oddly specific. Where is this problem from, exactly? And are you supposed to calculate it by hand?

Comment: 2019 since it's a big number and like, its the year 2019. I was just curious if this could be computed for numbers above 1000, and if so, numbers above 2000.

Comment: And do you have any reason to believe that it can be done more easily than what you did for $x=6$, or are you just curious as to whether it's possible?

Comment: My teacher came across this problem and gave it to the class, and apparently it can be solved using elementary math techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a well-known expression for the Euler function using the Möbius function:
  $$ \varphi(n) = n\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu(d)}d. $$
Consequently,
\begin{align}
   \sum_{n=1}^N \varphi(n) 
       &= \sum_{n=1}^N n \sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)}d \\
       &= \sum_{d=1}^N \frac{\mu(d)}d \sum_{k\le N/d} kd \\
       &= \frac12\,\sum_{d=1}^N \mu(d) \left\lfloor \frac Nd\right \rfloor \left(\left\lfloor \frac Nd\right \rfloor +1\right). 
\end{align}
This expression is standartly used to give an asymptotic for the sum in the LHS, but it also can be used to efficiently calculate this sum.